# Pass a variable to Ajax URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a variable (integer) in URL to be used in an Ajax request:

In my HTML, I have:

```
<span class="user">15</span>
```

And the script:

```
$('#fileupload').click(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if (file.error != null) {
                    $console.text(file.error);
                }
                var user = parseInt($(".user").text(), 10);
                //Open the uploaded file//
                $.ajax({
                    url: "files/" + user + '/' + file.name,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (res) {
                        handsontable.loadData(res.data);
                        $console.text('Loaded file: ' + file.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, the variable (15) isn't being passed to the URL, I get the error:

```
/files/NaN/data.json
```

I know I'm doing something stupid, and searched everywhere, but what is it?

Comment: Do you have multiple `.user` elements on the page?

Comment: I guess that was the problem, I replaced the name with something else and it went OK! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to parse int it, because you're just putting it back into a string. Try removing the parse int then consol logging the value of the user variable.

Also, perhaps you have many user elements? Console log $(".user") to see if you get an array.

Comment: also, make sure you have only ONE object with the class `user` otherwise, try `$('.user')[0]`

Comment: That's right: too many users seemed to be the problem. Also, parseint wasn't really necessary, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parsing fails and you get `NaN` (not-a-number) instead.

Can you verify that the input string to `parseInt` looks like a number?

Also, you're converting `user` back into a string. Do you really need to `parseInt` here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to run `$('.user').text()` in chrome console (F12) (for example) to see if you have some empty value or thing like that.

I believe that this approach can help you.